# form_for filter query directing to create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Afternoon All,

I'm trying to put a filter in my rails application but when I process the below it redirects to the create action on submit and I cannot figure out why it would pass to this action:

jobs_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
    @show_sub_nav = true
    @lang = Job.find_by_sql("SELECT languages FROM jobs GROUP BY languages").map &:languages
    @list = params[:languages].blank? ? Job.all : Job.find_all_by_category(params[:languages])
  end
```

my view

```
 <%= form_tag(jobs_path :method => 'get', :action => 'index') do %>
       <%= select_tag "languages", options_for_select(@lang) %>
       <%= submit_tag "Filter" %>
<% end %>
```

I was playing around the the form_for() with different options but it doesn't seem to make any difference and here is the log on click:

```
Started POST "/jobs?method=get" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 19:35:54 +0000
Processing by JobsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"p34KrqtWpFr5xCAB+leP3YkVbJjLpDKix4BJDUZquAg=", "languages"=>"Ratke-Beatty", "commit"=>"Filter", "method"=>"get"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered jobs/_subregion_select.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered jobs/_form.html.erb (38.7ms)
  Rendered jobs/new.html.erb within layouts/application (39.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 75ms (Views: 54.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the following:

```
 <%= form_tag({ :action => "index"}, { :method => "get"}) do %>
```

Seems to work and gives me the right output.

Answer (score 0):

It redirects because you're setting the http type to GET with this: `:method => 'get'`.

Generally, forms POST data so you either want `:method => 'post'`, or if you're following the restful routes design, you don't need to specify the `:method` as rails is smart enough to know.

Comment: That's probably because `jobs_path` is a GET route. If you run `rake routes`, you can see all your routes.